# I can't run compass watch

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, bundler, compass-sass

When I try I get these errors:

```
/Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:352:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'rb-fchange (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:165:in `start'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `resolve'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in `resolve'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/compass-0.12.6/bin/compass:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/compass:23:in `load'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Which file I need to edit to detect the gem I install?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it. RVM is working the only problem be I need to go the folder project and type: **bundle install**